# For E a Normed Vector Space, What Is $\mathbb{R}^{E}$? (Brezis, Theorem 3.16)

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

I am currently reading Theorem 3.16 in Brezis's "Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces, and Partial Differential Equations".

The proof starts of: "Consider the Cartesian product $Y = \mathbb{R}^{E}$, which consists of all maps from $E$ into $\mathbb{R}$".

We denote the elements of $Y$ by $\omega = (\omega_{x})_{x \in E}$, with $\omega_{x} \in \mathbb{R}$. We equip the stanadard product topology to this space, which Brezis notes is the coarsest topology on $Y$ associated with the collection of maps $\omega \rightarrow \omega_{x}$. He then claims that this is "of course" the same as the topology of pointwise convergence.

I have found it hard to find a real definition of this set $Y = \mathbb{R}^{E}$, and I find this notation ambiguous. Each element of $Y$ is a function from $E$ into $\mathbb{R}$, but how exactly are we able to express this as a product of $E$ and $\mathbb{R}$? Could someone please point me to a fully fleshed out definition of $Y$ here?

Comment: $\Bbb R^E$ isn't the Cartesian product of $\Bbb R$ and $E$. Rather it is the Cartesian product of $|E|$ copies of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your response. So would it be possible to create a bijection between the set of maps between E and R, and this Cartesian product space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really a product, it's an "exponential object". In set theory (where this notation comes from), for sets $A$ and $B$, $A^B$ is by definition the set of functions from $B$ to $A$. The Cartesian product however of $A$ and $B$, $A \times B$, is the set of ordered pairs $\{(a,b): a \in A, b \in B\}$ which is a different object altogether.

As $2=\{0,1\}$ (in cardinals and ordinals, this is how the set $2$ is defined!) we can identify $A^2$ with $A \times A$ in an obvious way via a bijection that sends $(a,b) \in A \times B$ to the function $f: 2 \to A$ defined by $f(0)=a, f(1)=b$. So for *finite* products we usually identify the exponential $A^n$ with an $n$-fold product of copies of $A$. But note that they're not really the same set...

I'd better get used to thinking about these powers as exponential objects, i.e. sets of functions, not "tuples", except in the finite case, maybe.

And the product topology and "the topology of pointwise convergence" are common synomyms for the unique coarsest (smallest) topology that makes all "projections" (or evaluations, sending $f$ to $f(x)$ for some fixed $x$) continuous.

Comment: How can I construct such a bijection for infinite dimensions?

Comment: @DavidHughes There are no infinite tuples, really. It's just a notation for a certain function. If you write $(x_n)_n$ or $(x_0,x_1,x_2, \ldots)$ you just mean the function that sends $n$ to $x_n$. Just a convenient shorthand.

Comment: But I need to equip this space with the "standard product topology" so $\mathbb{R}^{E}$ should be equivalent to Euclidean space somehow no?

Comment: Is there a name for this kind of space that I can easily look up and read more into?

Comment: @DavidHughes Yes, define the projections $\pi_x: \mathbb{R}^E \to \mathbb{R}$ for any $x \in E$, by $\pi_x(f)=f(x)$ and then give this set the smallest topology such that all projections $\{\pi_x: x \in E\}$ are continuous. If you do this for $X \times X$ you get the two standard projections under the identification with $X^2$ that I gave.

Comment: @DavidHughes see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#Infinite_Cartesian_products) for example, and any good book on general topology, like Engelking or Willard, Kelley or Dugundji.

Answer (score 1):

The definition as it is stated is a full definition. A function $\omega: E \to \Bbb R$ can also be viewed as a very long tuple of elements in $\Bbb R$, with an entry $\omega_x$ for every $x \in E$. So you get $\omega(x) = \omega_x$, where the left side is viewing $\omega$ as a function, and the right side is viewing $\omega$ as a tuple.

Now where do tuples live? In a product, so we get
$$
\Bbb R^E = \prod_{x \in E} \Bbb R.
$$

Just a smaller example, if $E =\{0,1,2\}$ (so it is not a vector space now, but just a set). Then a function $\omega: E \to \Bbb R$ is just a tuple $(\omega_0, \omega_1, \omega_2)$ of three elements in $\Bbb R$. And we have in this case
$$
\Bbb R^E = \prod_{x \in E} \Bbb R = \Bbb R \times \Bbb R \times \Bbb R.
$$

---

Since you also mention the product topology, you may be interested in [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology) on that subject.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How do we decide the order of these entries in these tuples? For my class, I will likely be expected to construct this $\mathbb{R}^{E}$ properly.

Comment: @David There is no need to order them. A tuple is a family of elements, indexed by some set. The reason we usually view them as ordered is because finite tuples (when there is a finite amount of indices, like in my example) can always be ordered. But there is no real reason to order them, we do not need an "$x$th" entry, just entry with index $x$.

Comment: So, in finite dimensions, the vectors (1,2) and (2,1) are different, but you're saying that this sort of distinction doesn't exist in infinite dimensions?

Comment: @David No, what I am saying is that you can no longer necessarily order them. For example, if we have a tuple with an entry for every $x \in \mathbb{Q}^2$, then our tuple is not really ordered. It is more like a table of entries. Generally, for infinite $E$ and $x, y \in E$, we cannot necessarily say if $x < y$ or $y < x$. But this is not needed to make sense of tuples. We can perfectly well have two tuples $\omega$ and $\omega'$ such that $\omega_x = 1$, $\omega_y = 2$ and $\omega'_x = 2$, $\omega'_y = 1$. We can still distinguish between these tuples by looking at the entries at $x$ or $y$.

Comment: I wouldn't think of it as tupels, but just as functions. A tupel $(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ with elements in $X$ can be seen as a function $\{1, \dots, n\} \to X$ by $i \mapsto x_i$. Now, generalise this, and consider a tupel $(\omega_x)_{x \in X}$ as the map that sends $x \mapsto \omega_x$. In fact, this is the formal definition of product! Thus, by definition $\mathbb{R}^E$ is the set of all functions $E \to \mathbb{R}$. If you have such a function $f$, we sometimes write it as $(f_x)_{x \in E}$ or $(f(x))_{x \in E}$

Comment: @EpsilonDelta That identification is precisely the point of the answer and the thing that OP was not understanding about some proof.

Comment: Ok, but Brezis talks about equipping this space with the "standard product topology". He means the topology on Euclidean space right? So there should be an explicit way to show this space is equivalent to $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ no?

Comment: Is there a name for this kind of space that I can easily look up and read more into?

Comment: @David Well, $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ is not really well-defined, because it is not clear what kind of infinity is in the exponent. It may be countable (e.g. $\mathbb{Q}$) or uncountable (e.g. $\mathbb{R}$, and in fact there are many more different uncountable infinities). Anyway, you would call these things "product space" and the term "product topology" that Brezis uses is also standard. I have edited my answer to include a link with more explanation.

Comment: I see. I guess I had taken for granted that the infinity was the limit of increasing naturals. Thank you very much!

Comment: @David Usually in analysis it means that kind of thing, so I can see why you would think something like that. In more general settings it is better to be a bit more precise.